# Using apply() to manipulate multiple columns

Tags: r

I've got a cross-tab frequency table where the measure is CAG and columns A01, A02 etc are frequency counts. i.e. 6485 counts of 13 CAG, 35 counts of CAG 14.

I'm trying to:

1. Set all values in A01, A02 etc that are <0.2 the size of the highest value in that column (i.e. exclude those not meeting a 20% threshold).
2. Normalise each value in A01, A02 etc by dividing each value in that column by the sum of all values in that column. This will give a value between 0-1 for each row in the column.
3. Multiply each value in A01, A02 etc by the change in CAG. Change in CAG is the value in the CAG column minus the modal CAG value.
4. I then need to sum all the values in each column.

I've had a stab at it here, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to progress further. Would appreciate any help!

```
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
               A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
               A02 = c(0,42,56, 4))
iithreshold <- 0.2

ii <- lapply(data[, 8:ncol(height)], function(x) {
  mod <- data$CAG[which.max(x)]
  x < (iithreshold * max(x)) <- 0
  ii2 <- (x / sum (x)) * (height$CAG - mod)
})

ii3 <- sum(ii2)

ii3 <- as.data.frame(ii3)
ii3 <- t(ii3)
```

Great news! I've now got it working and giving the right results. Thanks so much! I must have had a typo somewhere. I just restarted from scratch. This is the working code:

```
library(data.table) 
dataDT <- data.frame(height[,7:ncol(height)])
dataDT <- setDT(dataDT)
iithreshold <- 0.2

colsToBeUsed<-names(dataDT[,!'CAG'])
sumDataSetdata<-c()
iiht<-unlist(lapply(X=1:length(colsToBeUsed),function(X){s=colsToBeUsed[X]
eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[',s,'<iithreshold*max(',s,'),',s,':=0]'))) 
eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,MAX',s,':=dataDT[',s,'==max(',s,'),CAG]]')))
eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,norm',s,':=',s,'/sum(',s,')]')))
eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,sum',s,':=',s,'/sum(',s,')*(CAG-MAX',s,'),]')))
eval(parse(text=paste0('rbind(sumDataSetdata,dataDT[,sum(sum',s,')])')))
}))
```

I've been going through trying to understand what each of your lines of functions do, but am still not sure. For my education I don't suppose you would be able to let me know what each is doing? 
Thank you again!

Comment: Is there a certain need to do the manipulation of the data in this way (without using either data.table or dplyr packages?I think that using one of these will make your code, faster and more compact.

Comment: No, happy to use other packages asking as I get to the end result. How would you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I would not go with base R for data manipulation, although this is possible. I would use either data.table or dplyr packages for that.

I have to note that this is not the only way to go and the overhead of data table has to be taken into account and then decide between the two aforementioned packages.

Since you have `n` number of columns, I think that the use of `.SD` along with `.SDcols` is what you need in data.table terms.
For example let say you have A01 to A0n columns. Then you can have:

```
colsToBeUsed=names(data[,!('CAG')])  

data[ , lapply(.SD, {your formula as a function}), .SDCols=c(colsToBeUsed)]
```

In any case, in base R lapply is faster that for loops that is why I would recommend the use of lapply.

After getting a comment about a way to do the coding, I provide two options: 
First with for loop:

```
library(data.table)
dataDT<- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
                   A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
                   A02 = c(0,42,56, 4))
thres <- 0.2
dataDT<-setDT(dataDT)
colsToBeUsed<-names(dataDT[,!'CAG'])
sumDataSetdata<-c()  


for(X in colsToBeUsed){
  eval(parse(text=paste0("dataDT[",X,"<thres*max(",X,"),",X,":=0]")))
  eval(parse(text=paste0("dataDT[,MAX",X,":=dataDT[",X,"==max(",X,"),CAG]]")))
  eval(parse(text=paste0("dataDT[,norm",X,":=",X,"/sum(",X,")]")))
  eval(parse(text=paste0("dataDT[,sum",X,":=",X,"/sum(",X,")*(CAG-MAX",X,"),]")))
  eval(parse(text=paste0("sumDataSetdata<-rbind(sumDataSetdata,dataDT[,sum(sum",X,")])")))
  }
```

Second with lapply:

```
library(data.table)
dataDT<- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
                    A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
                    A02 = c(0,42,56, 4))

thres <- 0.2
dataDT<-setDT(dataDT)

colsToBeUsed<-names(dataDT[,!'CAG'])
sumDataSetdata<-c()
sumDataSet<-unlist(lapply(X=1:length(colsToBeUsed),function(X){s=colsToBeUsed[X]
  eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[',s,'<thres*max(',s,'),',s,':=0]')))
  eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,MAX',s,':=dataDT[',s,'==max(',s,'),CAG]]')))
  eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,norm',s,':=',s,'/sum(',s,')]')))
  eval(parse(text=paste0('dataDT[,sum',s,':=',s,'/sum(',s,')*(CAG-MAX',s,'),]')))
  eval(parse(text=paste0('rbind(sumDataSetdata,dataDT[,sum(sum',s,')])')))
  }))
```

Comment: Thank you both. I have n number of columns depending on the experiment. Would you recommend using lapply() or for loops perhaps to apply formulae to multiple columns?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm still not quite there understanding it yet. I've replied above

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could post an example of code using .SD

Comment: Sorry for the late answer...This is the easiest :  
`data[, lapply(.SD, sum),  .SDcols=c(colsToBeUsed)]`  
and for a custom function:  
`data[, lapply(.SD, function(X){X/sum(X)}),  .SDcols=c(colsToBeUsed)]`

Comment: Thank you. I'm really sorry, but I've not used .SD before and am having a hard time picturing how to code it. Is there any chance you would be able to write the code out using my example above in an answer that I can run to see it in action?

Comment: I'm also getting an error with you're first line of code: Error in !("CAG") : invalid argument type

Comment: @Mike Hi, please check above.

Comment: Thanks. I've adapted lapply function to my real data. Cols are called 'A01_RR20170609_FA_A01_2017-06-09_1.fsa', 'A02_RR20170609_FA_A02_2017-06-09_1.fsa' etc. Only change to your code was fill dataDT with a table called 'height'    dataDT<- height[,7:ncol(height)]     . Col7 onward is same format as 'data' - col7 is CAG. Unfortunately it gives the following error:     Error in parse(text = paste0("dataDT[", s, "<thres*max(", s, "),", s,  : 
  <text>:1:40: unexpected input
1: dataDT[A01_RR20170609_FA_A01_2017-06-09_
                                           ^

Comment: I don't think the problem is the column names, because I changed the names in your example using the 'data' table and it worked fine. I'd be grateful for your thoughts

Comment: @Mike, Could you please provide where you declare height? I believe that the point is height is not data.table but only data.frame

Comment: Thank you. 'height' is a data frame, though I though setDT() would convert it. I've pasted the code in my previous answer, but class(dataDT) does give a confusing answer:  "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: I've tried calling 'height' in as a list, but unfortunately still get the same error. dataDT<- list(height[,7:ncol(height)])

Comment: Just to clarify, class(height) gives: 
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: However, I note that dataDT using the example in this question (CAG 13, 14, 15, 17) also gives [1] "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147778/discussion-between-npt-and-mike).